# Data Tips in Visual Studio on Release Configuration

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, configuration, visual-studio-2017

How can I get Visual Studio 2017 to display data tips while running in Release Mode rather than only in Debug Mode?

Data tips are the tool tips that pop up when hovering the mouse over a property, variable, etc. while paused on a breakpoint.

I've read that these are only displayed while running in "Debug" configuration, but for one of my current projects, the program will only run correctly while in "Release" configuration.  This is making it extremely difficult to debug anything.

**UPDATE:**

Today it started working for me without me having changed anything.

The only explanation I have is that on the previous night I switched to Debug mode, built the application (which failed with errors), then switched back to Release mode, and built again.  When I ran the application the next morning, the data tips were back.

Comment: Since it works well now, I just post the possible answer for this issue. One possible reason is that it was related to your VS settings like my previous answer, or it is related to your project files' loaded. Anyway, I just edit my answer for it, so it could help other community members who get the same issue.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Good idea.  I added a hypothesis of my own that might partly explain what happened.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your solution as an answer(not in your question)? So you could mark it as the answer, and we could close this case. Have a nice day:)

Comment: I would argue that it's not really a solution since the cause is still unknown, and since I can't prove that what I did was related, the answer is also unknown.

Comment: I just add possible reasons as the answer, maybe we could close this case since it works well now. Of course, as you said that it has certain error messages before, maybe the error could provide some information. Anyway, glad to know that this issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Disable Optimize Code option under your project properties.

(2) Enable Use Managed Compatibility Mode under Tools->Options->Debugging->General.

And then debug your app in release mode, check it again after the Breakpoint is hit.

(3) Maybe it was related to your project files, so you could re-open your project, view it again.